# Jsoup 403 error and Android user agent

Tags: android, httpresponse, user-agent, jsoup

I want to parse an external webpage with Jsoup in an android app. Actually I manage to do it except it's the mobile version. So... I tried to set User Agent to something else than a "mobile" one.

The problem is that with .userAgent() option and .header(), IOException returns 403 error.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2").get();
```

And the Http Response :

```
Date    Mon, 12 Dec 2011 04:08:38 GMT
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
Connection  keep-alive
P3P CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"
Cache-Control   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Expires Mon, 12 Dec 2011 00:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified   Mon, 12 Dec 2011 04:08:38 GMT
Pragma  no-cache
X-Content-Type-Options  nosniff
X-XSS-Protection    1; mode=block
Content-Encoding    gzip
```

Is there something here preventing the connection ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your request is most likely getting blocked by your mobile data carrier (they only allow mobile User-Agents).

Comment: I received confirmation from them some times ago. Meanwhile I switched to another data carrier with fair-use option. It works perfectly.

It is obviously not the right thing to do...
I think the best is to get a webservice dedicated to mobile.

Thanks for your reply !